# Unpacking complex nested C structs in Python

Tags: python, c, struct, nested, unpack

This is a follow-up question to [my previous question, "Unpacking nested C structs in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082211/unpacking-nested-c-structs-in-python). The structs I am working with have since become more complex and I am once again not sure how to unpack and handle them completely.

On the C side, the relevant part of the header looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t seq;
    uint8_t type;
    uint16_t flags;
    uint16_t upTimestamp;
}__attribute__ ((packed)) mps_packet_header;

typedef struct {
    mps_packet_header header;
    int16_t x[6];
    int16_t y[6];
    int16_t z[6];
    uint16_t lowTimestmp[6];
}__attribute__ ((packed)) mps_acc_packet_t;
typedef mps_acc_packet_t accpacket_t;

typedef struct {
    int16_t hb1;
    int16_t hb2;
} acam_hb_data_set;

typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)) {
    mps_packet_header header;
    uint16_t temp;
    uint16_t lowTimestmp[8];
    acam_hb_data_set dms_data[8];
} mps_dms_packet_t;
```

Two challenges arise from this. First, packets I receive (in binary form) can be either `mps_acc_packet_t` or `mps_dms_packet_t` - the only way to tell them apart is to read the `type` field in the `mps_packet_header` which both packet types have. This means that I need to unpack the packet before I know its full contents, which I don't know how to do cleanly as (if I'm not mistaken) the two packet types have a different `calcsize` (54 and 56 respectively). The second challenge is unpacking an `mps_dms_packet_t`; as you can see from the struct's definition, this packet has an array consisting of 8 instances of `acam_hb_data_set`, which in turn is a struct consisting of two `int16` values. I don't know how to formulate a correct format string for this.

My previous code (before `mps_dms_packet_t` was introduced) looked like this, as suggested by [falsetru in his answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082713/2656964):

```
s = struct.Struct('= B B H H 6h 6h 6h 6H')
fields = s.unpack(packet_data)
seq, _type, flags, upTimestamp = fields[:4]
x = fields[4:10]
y = fields[10:16]
z = fields[16:22]
lowTimestamp = fields[22:]
```

This worked fine. Now, I need to somehow be able to read the header (for which I need to unpack the struct) and then unpack the struct correctly depending on its type.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

Try `ctypes`. It is more readable and easier to pack/unpack data with.

```
import ctypes

class mps_packet_header(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("seq", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("type", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("flags", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("upTimestamp", ctypes.c_uint16)
    ]

class mps_acc_packet_t(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("header", mps_packet_header),
        ("x", ctypes.c_int16 * 6),
        ("y", ctypes.c_int16 * 6),
        ("z", ctypes.c_int16 * 6),
        ("lowTimestmp", ctypes.c_uint16 * 6)
    ]

class acam_hb_data_set(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("hb1", ctypes.c_int16),
        ("hb2", ctypes.c_int16),
    ]


class mps_dms_packet_t(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("header", mps_packet_header),
        ("temp", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("lowTimestmp", ctypes.c_uint16 * 8),
        ("dms_data", acam_hb_data_set * 8)
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written [this](https://github.com/lu-maca/py-packed-struct/tree/main) small package that is based on the `bitstruct` package. Basically it allows you to do what you can already implement as per the previous answer, but including the possibility to add bit fields in the python side.

For example

```c
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    uint8_t number;
    char brand[10];
} shoes_t;

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    char tshirt[10];
    char shorts[10];
    shoes_t shoes;
} clothes_t;

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    char name[10];
    uint8_t age;
    float weight;
    clothes_t clothes;
} person_t;
```

is represented as:

```py
shoes_t =  Struct(
    {
        "number": c_unsigned_int(8),
        "brand": c_char(10*8)
    }
)

dresses_t =  Struct(
    {
        "tshirt": c_char(10*8),
        "shorts": c_char(10*8),
        "shoes": shoes_t
    }
)

person_t = Struct(
    {
        "name": c_char(10*8),
        "age": c_unsigned_int(8),
        "weight": c_float(32),
        "dresses": dresses_t
    }
)
```

The `Struct` class exposes the `pack` and `unpack` methods.

You can find an example of usage [here](https://github.com/lu-maca/py-packed-struct/tree/main#example)